# LINQ to Entities and subquery

Tags: linq-to-entities, entities

I try to move data model to OData. Itry to find a solution for nested query for quite long time.

We need to get absences in given project.

Our database schema + entities schema is:

- Absences - absences of ALL user in ALL projects.
- Project - list of projects
- TeamMember -  team members tale with relation to Project table. UserID here should be the same as in Absence in case of absence record.

SQL QUERY:

SELECT [Id], [UserId], [Date] FROM [Absence] WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM TeamMember WHERE ProjectId={0})

The problem for us is to write similar LINQ to Entities query

Anyone willing to help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
from a in Absence
where TeamMember.Any(t => t.UserId == a.UserId && t.ProjectId == projectId)
select a
```